# boot-folder too small for upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, boot, upgrade, 13.04

When updating my Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 I get the message

```
'Your boot folder is too small, make more space'
```

although my harddrive has still plenty of place left.

How can I make that boot folder bigger?

Comment: Does your boot folder lives on a different partition? Maybe that partition is too small to add another kernel image.

Comment: show us the result of `df -H`. Mind you: if you have a /boot in there ... that partition is too small;so remove kernels ;)

Comment: I get a pop up when trying to update my Ubuntu. The upgrade needs a total of 26.7M free space on disk'/boot'. Please free at least an additional 10.6M of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and temp packages of former installation using sudo apt-get clean I tried this and above and I am not able to clear out more files. I am not allowed to delete files. I am the admin on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Determine which kernel you're running, via `uname -r`. Remember this - don't delete anything with this version.

See which kernels, tools, etc you have installed, with:

```
dpkg -l linux-image\*
dpkg -l linux-headers\*
dpkg -l linux-tools\*
```

Carefully avoiding the current version (shown by `uname -r`), delete older versions using `sudo apt-get remove ...` and `sudo apt-get purge ...`.

If you can't get enough space the above way, you'll have to switch to **Plan B**.

Plan B is:

Read `man gparted`

Boot from a live CD containing `gparted`.

Use `gparted` to shrink one of the partitions next to `/boot`, and expand `/boot` into the newly freed space.